# R: Cumulative sum if difference over threshold

Tags: r, vector, cumsum

I have a vector of numbers

```
x <- c(0, 28, 59, 89, 0, 15, 16, 0, 35, 31)
#[1] 0 0 31 30 0 15 16 0 35 31
```

And I would like to calculate the cumulative sum of it, for a special condition. Given:

```
month_vec <- seq(as.Date("2009-02-01"), length = 10, by = "1 month") - 1
day_vec   <- as.numeric(substr(month_vec, 9, 10))
# > day_vec
#[1] 31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31
```

I only want to `cumsum(x)` if the difference to the element before is greater or equal than the value in `day_vec`.

The result should look like this:

```
my_custom_cumsum(x)
#[1] 0 0 31 61 0 15 16 0 35 66
```

Because `x[4]` is equal to `day_vec[4]`, `x[3]` and `x[4]`are cumsummed. However, `x[6]` and `x[7]` are not cumsummed because they are smaller than their respective position in `day_vec`. But `x[9]` and `x[10]` should be cumsummed again - in other words: **The cumsum should reset if the difference to the element before is smaller than the value in `day_vec`**. Does anybody have an idea of how to solve this elegantly?

Comment: x and day_vec are not of the same length - is that supposed to be like that?

Comment: No, a typical copy-paste error. I increased the length of day_vec to 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this with a logical index used for subsetting. It should be true for all elements of x that shall be "cumsumed" and false for the rest.

```
idx <- x >= day_vec
```

Now you can use it to compute the cumsum and assign it to the correct elements in x:

```
x[idx] <- cumsum(x[idx])
x
#[1]  0  0 31 61  0 15 16
```

Comment: my question was not totally accurate. The cumsum should reset if the difference to the element before is smaller than the value in `day_vec`. See my edit with a longer vector.